# When creating a new product, auto assign it to all custom taxonomy woocommerce

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin

I have a custom taxonomy called Location, and there are a lot of parents and children categories on it to mark in which location the product is available. They are available in the most of the categories so I end up expending too much time ticking them.

Is it possible to include a function to tick all the categories and I just need to untick the locations where it is not available?

Answer (score 0):

For post types not using the block editor, you can use [`wp_terms_checklist_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_terms_checklist_args/) filter to manipulate the selected terms of a hierarchical taxonomy. You can use the filter to set pre-selected terms like so,

```
function auto_check_hierarchial_terms_on_new_post( $args, $post_id ) {
  // is it new post?
  if ( 'auto-draft' !== get_post_status($post_id) ) {
    return $args;
  }
  // is it my taxonomy?
  if ( 'my_custom_taxonomy' !== $args['taxonomy'] ) {
    return $args;
  }
  // let's not overwrite anything by accident
  if ( ! empty( $args['selected_cats'] ) ) {
    return $args;
  }
  // get existing terms
  $terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => $args['taxonomy'],
    'hide_empty' => false,
  ) );
  if ( ! $terms || ! is_array( $terms ) ) {
    return $args;
  }
  // pre select all terms
  $args['selected_cats'] = array();
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $args['selected_cats'][] = $term->term_id;
  }
  return $args;
}    
add_filter('wp_terms_checklist_args', 'auto_check_hierarchial_terms_on_new_post', 10, 2);
```

There's a [note on the filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_terms_checklist_args/#user-contributed-notes), that it seems to be obsolete for WP 5 block editor.

Comment: Than kyou for replying, but it didnt work :/